# Template/XSLT and javaScript 1.0 Difference between two value not working properly

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to calculate difference between date and number for all of the xml element specified, but it only calculate and get the last element within xml.

E.g.: I have two birthday, but it only collect the second one for all calculation.

The main goal is to display difference between two date in days for every person.

Below are XSLT code and XML code:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Sample JS</title>
            <script>
                window.onload = function() {
                    var all = document.querySelectorAll('.date');
                    var all2 = document.querySelectorAll('.date2');

                    for(element of all) {
                        date = new Date(element.innerHTML);


                    }
                    for(element of all2) {
                        date2 = new Date(element.innerHTML);

                        difference = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date.getTime());
                        days = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
                        element.innerHTML = days;
                    }

                    var numb = document.querySelectorAll('.num1');
                    var numb2 = document.querySelectorAll('.num2');

                    for(element of numb) {
                        num1 = element.innerHTML;
                    }
                    for(element of numb2) {


                        num2 = element.innerHTML;

                        difference =  num2 - num1;
                        element.innerHTML = difference;
                    }
                }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="people/person" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="person">
     <p>Birthday: <span class="date"><xsl:value-of select="dob/text()"/></span></p>
     <p>Death day: <xsl:value-of select="dod/text()"/></p>
    <p>Difference: <span class="date2"><xsl:value-of select="dod/text()"/></span></p>
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="num2/text()"/> - 
        <span class="num1"><xsl:value-of select="num/text()"/></span> = 
        <span class="num2"><xsl:value-of select="num2/text()"/></span> 
    </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="js-example.xsl"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <dob>2017-09-01</dob>
        <dod>2017-09-08</dod>
        <num>1</num>
        <num2>30</num2>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Sarah</name>
        <dob>2017-09-10</dob>
        <dod>2017-09-07</dod>
        <num>10</num>
        <num2>20</num2>
    </person>
</people>
```

Output:

```
Birthday: 2017-09-01

Death day: 2017-09-08

Difference: 2

30 - 1 = 20

Birthday: 2017-09-10

Death day: 2017-09-07

Difference: 3

20 - 10 = 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop:

```
for(element of all) {
  date = new Date(element.innerHTML);
}
```

you loop over all the values of *all*, but each loop overwrites the previous value of *date*.

You should also declare all variables like *date* with *var*, otherwise they become when the code runs.

Assuming the elements in *all* and *all2* are correlated by position in their respective collections, you likely need something like:

```
// Declare all variables
var all = document.querySelectorAll('.date');
var all2 = document.querySelectorAll('.date2');
var date1, date2, difference, days;

for (var i=0, iLen=all.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  date1 = new Date(all[i].innerHTML);
  date2 = new Date(all2[i].innerHTML);

  difference = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
  days = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  // This will replace the date in all2
  all2[i].innerHTML = days;
}
```

Note that not all days are 24 hours long in places that daylight saving is used so:

```
 days = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

may return the incorrect value where daylight saving boundaries are involved.

Comment: Great Explanation, Thank you!